# how to show legend in PIE chart from chart to pie drilldown highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, highcharts

I want to know how can i show legend for the pie chart, i currently done a column to pie chart drilldown but for the pie chart there is no legend and i want to know how can i put it?
I tried putting legend = true but it is still not showing in the pie chart.

I have also tried:

pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
}

my code below:

```html
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart showing the total vs match dialogs'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    var mychart = $('#container').highcharts();
                    var mytotal = 0;

                    for (i = 0; i < mychart.series.length; i++) {
                        if (mychart.series[i].visible) {
                            mytotal = {!! $countTotalRecord['low confidence'] !!} + {!! $countTotalRecord['no answer'] !!} + {!! $countTotalRecord['missing intent'] !!} + {!! $countTotalRecord['webhook fail'] !!};
                        }
                    }
                    var pcnt = (this.y / mytotal) * 100;
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        // headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },

    credits:{
      enabled:false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'front',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Total',
            y: {!! $countTotalRecord['total'] !!},
            drilldown: 'total'
        }, {
            name: 'Match',
            y: {!! $countTotalRecord['match'] !!},
            drilldown: 'match'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'total',
            id: 'total',
            type:'pie',
            data: [
                [
                    'Low Confidence',
                    {!! $countTotalRecord['low confidence'] !!}
                ],
                [
                    'No Answer',
                    {!! $countTotalRecord['no answer'] !!}
                ],
                [
                    'Missing Intent',
                    {!! $countTotalRecord['missing intent'] !!}
                ],
                [
                    'Webhook Fail',
                    {!! $countTotalRecord['webhook fail'] !!}
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
 events: {
  drilldown: function(e) {
    this.options.legend["enabled"] = true; //legend shows
  },
  drillup: function(e) {
    this.options.legend["enabled"] = false; //legend hides
  },

}
```

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        this.options.legend["enabled"] = true;
      },
      drillup: function(e) {
        this.options.legend["enabled"] = false;
      },

    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Total percent market share'
    }

  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
      }
    },
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,

    data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33,
      drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
    }, {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 24.03,
      drilldown: 'Chrome'
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.38,
      drilldown: 'Firefox'
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.77,
      drilldown: 'Safari'
    }, {
      name: 'Opera',
      y: 0.91,
      drilldown: 'Opera'
    }, {
      name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
      y: 0.2,
      drilldown: null
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      data: [
        [
          'v11.0',
          24.13
        ],
        [
          'v8.0',
          17.2
        ],
        [
          'v9.0',
          8.11
        ],
        [
          'v10.0',
          5.33
        ],
        [
          'v6.0',
          1.06
        ],
        [
          'v7.0',
          0.5
        ]
      ]
    }, {
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Chrome',
      id: 'Chrome',
      data: [
        [
          'v40.0',
          5
        ],
        [
          'v41.0',
          4.32
        ],
        [
          'v42.0',
          3.68
        ],
        [
          'v39.0',
          2.96
        ],
        [
          'v36.0',
          2.53
        ],
        [
          'v43.0',
          1.45
        ],
        [
          'v31.0',
          1.24
        ],
        [
          'v35.0',
          0.85
        ],
        [
          'v38.0',
          0.6
        ],
        [
          'v32.0',
          0.55
        ],
        [
          'v37.0',
          0.38
        ],
        [
          'v33.0',
          0.19
        ],
        [
          'v34.0',
          0.14
        ],
        [
          'v30.0',
          0.14
        ]
      ]
    }, {
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Firefox',
      id: 'Firefox',
      data: [
        [
          'v35',
          2.76
        ],
        [
          'v36',
          2.32
        ],
        [
          'v37',
          2.31
        ],
        [
          'v34',
          1.27
        ],
        [
          'v38',
          1.02
        ],
        [
          'v31',
          0.33
        ],
        [
          'v33',
          0.22
        ],
        [
          'v32',
          0.15
        ]
      ]
    }, {
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Safari',
      id: 'Safari',
      data: [
        [
          'v8.0',
          2.56
        ],
        [
          'v7.1',
          0.77
        ],
        [
          'v5.1',
          0.42
        ],
        [
          'v5.0',
          0.3
        ],
        [
          'v6.1',
          0.29
        ],
        [
          'v7.0',
          0.26
        ],
        [
          'v6.2',
          0.17
        ]
      ]
    }, {
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Opera',
      id: 'Opera',
      data: [
        [
          'v12.x',
          0.34
        ],
        [
          'v28',
          0.24
        ],
        [
          'v27',
          0.17
        ],
        [
          'v29',
          0.16
        ]
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
legend: {
    enabled: true
},
...
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.